# How do I tell AppleScript to read the contents of the "Network" Finder window?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, applescript

I'd like to be able to get the contents of Finder's "Network" folder (Menubar-->Go-->Network). The folder contents here is different than /Network or /net.

The overall goal is to grep the names in this folder for a specific (unmanaged...) Mac in my environment. I don't know where it is, I just have the local host name. I was thinking about deploying a script to run dns-sd, but that binary is not too friendly to BASH script. Which is why I'm looking into Applescript now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Network Finder window isn't a folder. Attempting to get the location of Network gives the following error:

```
Can’t make «class cfol» "" of application "Finder" into type alias. (-1700)
```

…and attempting to get the location of the containing folder gives:

```
No result was returned from some part of this expression. (-2763)
```

Therefore I believe that Network is not a folder.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was worried this was the case.